# VUEJS: Property or method "indicatorTitle" is not defined

Tags: html, vue.js

Tenho uma variável simples e quero passa-la para meu v-for. Porém, recebo o erro "Property or method "indicatorTitle" is not defined on the instance but referenced".

O modo como estou tentando:

````
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md" v-for="title in titles" v-bind:key="title.indicatorTitle">
     {{ indicatorTitle }}
                            <div class="card" >
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <ul> 
                                        <li class="groupCategory">           
                                                
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

data: function () {
    return {
        titles: [
        { indicatorTitle: "Teste 3" },
        { indicatorTitle: "Teste 2" }, 
        { indicatorTitle: "Teste 1" }
        ]
    }
```
````

Comment: tens de o chamar a partir do objecto: `{{ title.indicatorTitle }}`

Comment: Ish, tens razão, esqueci completamente. Muito obrigada

Comment: @HelderLucas: vai uma resposta? :)

Comment: Vou aceitar a resposta com prazer quando a fizer, @HelderLucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendo `titles` um objecto,`indicatorTitle` tem que ser chamado como uma propriedade do mesmo, como por exemplo: `{{ title.indicatorTitle }}` :)

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta! :)